# How to rename a file inside a 7zip archive by CLI?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, archive, 7zip

I am looking for soulution how to rename files inside a 7zip archive by command line (unix).

Comment: I am not sure that this is programming related, and therefore doesn't belong here

Comment: Maybe youre right musefan, but I need this solutin to build some script to batch rename some files in archived files from my backup mechanism.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Unix tool p7zip is based on 7zip and should support the same command line options, which are documented in its help file.

To rename from the CLI, you'll need version 9.30 or above, and to rename multiple files in one go you'll need at least version 15.05 (which might not yet be ported):

http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt

The syntax to rename files inside archives is

```
7za rn <archive_name> <src_file_1> <dest_file_1> [ <src_file_2> <dest_file_2> ... ]
```

It also allows to move files around, e.g. into a subdirectory:

```
7za rn archive.7z old.txt new/location/new.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work, for this command: `7za rn main.zip main.c graph.c` I get this error: `Incorrect command line`

Comment: `Incorrect commandline` is probably because you have too old a version - check with `7za --help`