# Is it possible to move files within a zip file?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, zip, zsh

```
example.zip/
└── example/
    ├── nice.md
    ├── tree.md
    └── diagram.md

Expected:
example.zip/
├── nice.md
├── tree.md
└── diagram.md
```

`example.zip` contains a folder with the same name. In it are files that I want to move to the root of the zip file and remove the empty directory.

I looked at the zip man page. Could not find any flags related to the issue or I could be missing something.

I tried the `--copy-entries` flag. This create a new zip with selected files from the existing zip but also copy over the folder hierarchy.

`zip example.zip "*.md" --copy-entries --out example1.zip`

I am trying to write a shell script to do this.

Is it possible to do without extracting the zip?

Comment: Not really. For some zip files it might be possible if you don't mind using a hex editor. Requires a good understanding of the structure of a zip file and a lot of patience. Only practical approach is to unzip, rename and zip.

Answer (score 3):

If you have (or can install) `7z` (aka `p7zip`) you can make use of the `d`(delete) and `rn`(rename) options, eg:

```
$ mkdir example
$ touch example/{nice.md,tree.md,diagram.md}

$ zip -r example.zip example
  adding: example/ (stored 0%)
  adding: example/diagram.md (stored 0%)
  adding: example/nice.md (stored 0%)
  adding: example/tree.md (stored 0%)

$ unzip -l example.zip
Archive:  example.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   example/
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   example/diagram.md
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   example/nice.md
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   example/tree.md
---------                     -------
        0                     4 files

# rename the *.md files first and then delete the directory; if you delete
# the directory first you'll lose all files under the directory; the 7z d/rn 
# commands will generate a lot of output (not shown here)

$ 7z rn example.zip example/nice.md    nice.md
$ 7z rn example.zip example/tree.md    tree.md
$ 7z rn example.zip example/diagram.md diagram.md
$ 7z  d example.zip example

$ unzip -l example.zip
Archive:  example.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   diagram.md
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   nice.md
        0  09-15-2022 09:29   tree.md
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files

$ unzip example.zip
Archive:  example.zip
 extracting: diagram.md
 extracting: nice.md
 extracting: tree.md
```

I'm guessing in OP's real life example the names of the directories and/or files may not be known in advance; the `7z` commands do work with `bash` variables (eg, `7z d "${zipfile}" "${dir_to_delete}"`); if OP has issues dynamically processing the contents of a given *zip then I'd recommend asking a new question ...

---

For a large number of renames (or deletes) it looks like you can also:

- specify [multiple source/destination pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31964851) on the single command line
- use a [list file](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/3a1961c0/#453b)

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: The command worked but the zip file did not change.

Comment: @FrankShrestha can you update the question to show a) the unzip -l output from before the operation, b) the 7z commands you ran and c) the unzip -l output after the operation? also the version (see first line of output from 7z --help), in my case I'm running 15.14; I just ran all the code again (with empty and non-empty files) and everything works as shown in the answer ...

Answer (score -1):

Good answer. Just to be clear, 7z does not do an in-place edit on the zip file when it does the rename/delete. Under the hood it copies the old zip into a temporary file (`example.zip.tmp` in this instance), renaming & deleting as it does that copy. Then it deletes the original zip file and renames the temporary file, `example.zip.tmp` back to original filename, `example.zip`. For the most part this is a perfectly acceptable (and safe) approach.

Here are the relevant lines from an `strace` run that shows the deletion of th eoriginal `example.zip` file, followed by renaming the `example.zip.tmp` file to `example.zip`.

```
$ strace 7z rn example.zip example/tree.md    tree.md 
...
unlink("example.zip")                   = 0
rename("example.zip.tmp", "example.zip") = 0
...
```

Main edge condition of this approach is with very large zip files where you are strapped for disk space -- you need to have space available to store the zip file twice when it creates the temporary copy.